# Are human beings just a condensed form of "energy"?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

Since Einstein says $E = m  c^2$ and $m = E /c^2$. Does this mean that human beings (which can be represented as finite mass $m$) are actually just an condensed energy?

Comment: I don't see why people are voting to close this as unclear...I find it very clear.

Answer (score 3):

$E=mc^2$ says everything with mass is really equal to a whole lot of energy. So, yes. But don't think we can just press a magical button and convert a human to pure energy. That'd be hard for reasons ranging from "don't convert Bob to pure energy! I like Bob" to scientific (obviously, the scientific ones are the bigger problem).

Hope this helps!

[This website](http://www.universetoday.com/114617/a-fun-way-of-understanding-emc2/) has a fun calculation of how much energy a human's mass is equivalent to.

Comment: @mub, does this answer your question or is there something I missed?